# Why can't my Drupal PHPUnit test seem to autoload a shared test fixture/utility class?

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, composer-php, phpunit

In my Drupal 10.x project, I have a test that is attempting to mock a class that I created to be used by multiple tests (call it `Drupal\Tests\my_module\MyTestObject`). The code looks something like this:

```php
protected function setUpMocks(): void {
  $myMockObject = $this->createMock(MyTestObject::class);
}
```

I've checked the name of the class, the name of the file it's defined in, and the entire directory path to the file, but no matter what, I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\UnknownTypeException: Class or interface "Drupal\Tests\my_module\Utilities\MyTestObject" does not exist
```

In addition, if I define an abstract class above the test class that extends the class (see below), then PHP indicates it cannot find the base class:

```php
namespace Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\my_module\Utilities\MyTestObject;

// PHP fails to locate the MyTestObject base class.
abstract class SomeClass extends MyTestObject {
}

/**
 * My functional tests.
 */
class SomeTest extends BrowserTestBase {
  // ...
}
```

Why is this class not autoloading? It seems like PHP can find other test classes that are in nearly the same package without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm about 95% sure that the answer lies in `\Drupal\Core\Test\TestDiscovery::registerTestNamespaces()`. This method dynamically registers namespaces for each extension (module, theme, profile, etc.) with the class loader at run-time. Based on the following snippet, the method is only expecting to find test-related code under top-level folders that are specific to each test type, so code has to exist inside one of these paths for it to autoload properly:

```php
      $this->testNamespaces["Drupal\\Tests\\$name\\Unit\\"][] = "$base_path/tests/src/Unit";
      $this->testNamespaces["Drupal\\Tests\\$name\\Kernel\\"][] = "$base_path/tests/src/Kernel";
      $this->testNamespaces["Drupal\\Tests\\$name\\Functional\\"][] = "$base_path/tests/src/Functional";
      $this->testNamespaces["Drupal\\Tests\\$name\\Build\\"][] = "$base_path/tests/src/Build";
      $this->testNamespaces["Drupal\\Tests\\$name\\FunctionalJavascript\\"][] = "$base_path/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript";

      // Add discovery for traits which are shared between different test
      // suites.
      $this->testNamespaces["Drupal\\Tests\\$name\\Traits\\"][] = "$base_path/tests/src/Traits";
```

Since my class was in the namespace `Drupal\Tests\my_module\Utilities` (saved on disk as `web/modules/custom/my_module/tests/src/Utilities/MyTestObject.php`), this wasn't under one of the test namespaces so the file was not eligible for autoloading. Moving the class to `Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional\Utilities` worked, as would putting the class inside the `src/` of a module that gets installed by the tests. So, this is something to be aware of if you want to share test fixtures among both unit and functional tests.